# Include external JS file on one page Ionic 2

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2

I use `google maps` in `Ionic 2` project.
Script included in index.html page like

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=XXX"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

But the `google map script` is used only on one page, and it is loaded for everyone.
Can i include `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js` only for one page, example, in `component page`?

Answer (score 0):

You can import the script from your component page with the dom. My example below :

```
(id: string, src: string, callback?: Function): HTMLScriptElement => {
    if (document.getElementById(id)) {
        callback ? callback(true) : null;
        return;
    }
    let js, head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    js = document.createElement('script');
    js.id = id;
    js.src = src;
    js.onreadystatechange = js.onload = function () {
        if (callback && (!js.readyState || /loaded|complete/.test(js.readyState))) {
            callback();
        }
    };
    head.appendChild(js);
    return js;
}
```